# Can't update scala on Gentoo

Tags: java, gentoo

As I wanted to test Scala 2.9.2 on my gentoo system I tried updated the package but ended up with this error. I can't figure out where the problem may be:

```
Calculating dependencies  ...... done!
>>> Verifying ebuild manifests
>>> Jobs: 0 of 1 complete, 1 running                Load avg: 0.23, 0.16, 0.20
>>> Emerging (1 of 1) dev-lang/scala-2.9.2
>>> Jobs: 0 of 1 complete, 1 running                Load avg: 0.23, 0.16, 0.20
>>> Failed to emerge dev-lang/scala-2.9.2, Log file:
>>> Jobs: 0 of 1 complete, 1 running                Load avg: 0.23, 0.16, 0.20
>>>  '/var/tmp/portage/dev-lang/scala-2.9.2/temp/build.log'
>>> Jobs: 0 of 1 complete, 1 running                Load avg: 0.23, 0.16, 0.20
>>> Jobs: 0 of 1 complete, 1 running, 1 failed      Load avg: 0.23, 0.16, 0.20
>>> Jobs: 0 of 1 complete, 1 failed                 Load avg: 0.23, 0.16, 0.20

 * Package:    dev-lang/scala-2.9.2
 * Repository: gentoo
 * Maintainer: java@gentoo.org
 * USE:        amd64 elibc_glibc kernel_linux multilib userland_GNU
 * FEATURES:   sandbox
[01m[31;06m!!! ERROR: Couldn't find suitable VM. Possible invalid dependency string.
           Due to jdk-with-com-sun requiring a target of 1.7 but the virtual machines constrained by virtual/jdk-1.6  and/or
           this package requiring virtual(s) jdk-with-com-sun[0m
 * Unable to determine VM for building from dependencies:
NV_DEPEND: virtual/jdk:1.6
    java-virtuals/jdk-with-com-sun
    !binary? (
        dev-java/ant-contrib:0
    )
    app-arch/xz-utils >=dev-java/java-config-2.1.9-r1  source? ( app-arch/zip )  >=dev-java/ant-core-1.7.0
       dev-java/ant-nodeps

       >=dev-java/javatoolkit-0.3.0-r2
       >=dev-lang/python-2.4
 * ERROR: dev-lang/scala-2.9.2 failed (setup phase):
 *   Failed to determine VM for building.
 * 
 * Call stack:
 *             ebuild.sh, line   93:  Called pkg_setup
 *    scala-2.9.2.ebuild, line   43:  Called java-pkg-2_pkg_setup
 *     java-pkg-2.eclass, line   53:  Called java-pkg_init
 *   java-utils-2.eclass, line 2187:  Called java-pkg_switch-vm
 *   java-utils-2.eclass, line 2674:  Called die
 * The specific snippet of code:
 *                      die "Failed to determine VM for building."
 * 
 * If you need support, post the output of `emerge --info '=dev-lang/scala-2.9.2'`,
 * the complete build log and the output of `emerge -pqv '=dev-lang/scala-2.9.2'`.
!!! When you file a bug report, please include the following information:
GENTOO_VM=  CLASSPATH="" JAVA_HOME=""
JAVACFLAGS="" COMPILER=""
and of course, the output of emerge --info
 * The complete build log is located at '/var/tmp/portage/dev-lang/scala-2.9.2/temp/build.log'.
 * The ebuild environment file is located at '/var/tmp/portage/dev-lang/scala-2.9.2/temp/die.env'.
 * Working directory: '/var/tmp/portage/dev-lang/scala-2.9.2'
 * S: '/var/tmp/portage/dev-lang/scala-2.9.2/work/scala-2.9.2-sources'
 * Messages for package dev-lang/scala-2.9.2:
 * Unable to determine VM for building from dependencies:
 * ERROR: dev-lang/scala-2.9.2 failed (setup phase):
 *   Failed to determine VM for building.
 * 
 * Call stack:
 *             ebuild.sh, line   93:  Called pkg_setup
 *    scala-2.9.2.ebuild, line   43:  Called java-pkg-2_pkg_setup
 *     java-pkg-2.eclass, line   53:  Called java-pkg_init
 *   java-utils-2.eclass, line 2187:  Called java-pkg_switch-vm
 *   java-utils-2.eclass, line 2674:  Called die
 * The specific snippet of code:
 *                      die "Failed to determine VM for building."
 * 
 * If you need support, post the output of `emerge --info '=dev-lang/scala-2.9.2'`,
 * the complete build log and the output of `emerge -pqv '=dev-lang/scala-2.9.2'`.
 * The complete build log is located at '/var/tmp/portage/dev-lang/scala-2.9.2/temp/build.log'.
 * The ebuild environment file is located at '/var/tmp/portage/dev-lang/scala-2.9.2/temp/die.env'.
 * Working directory: '/var/tmp/portage/dev-lang/scala-2.9.2'
 * S: '/var/tmp/portage/dev-lang/scala-2.9.2/work/scala-2.9.2-sources'
```

The following eix output may help:

```
% eix java-virtuals/jdk-with-com-sun
[I] java-virtuals/jdk-with-com-sun
     Available versions:  20111111 {{ELIBC="FreeBSD"}}
     Installed versions:  20111111(16:08:51 18/04/12)(ELIBC="-FreeBSD")
     Homepage:            http://www.gentoo.org
     Description:         Virtual ebuilds that require internal com.sun classes from a JDK
```

Both virtual jdks 1.6 and 1.7 are installed:

```
% eix virtual/jdk
[I] virtual/jdk
     Available versions:  
        (1.4)   ~1.4.2-r1[1]
        (1.5)   1.5.0 ~1.5.0-r3[1]
        (1.6)   1.6.0 1.6.0-r1
        (1.7)   (~)1.7.0
     Installed versions:  1.6.0-r1(1.6)(23:22:48 10/11/12) 1.7.0(1.7)(23:21:09 10/11/12)
     Description:         Virtual for JDK

[1] "java-overlay" /var/lib/layman/java-overlay
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
emerge -1 java-config java-config-wrapper
```

It rebuilds Java environment configuration tool and java-config wrapper.

Answer (score 2):

I recently hit this same problem, and dastergon's fix was a necessary PART of the fix.  If after making sure both parts of java-config are installed, you're still seeing the error, there is a good chance it's because you don't have a JDK version 6 installed, or only the sun-jdk which no longer satisfied virtual/jdk:1.6

The fix for that is to install a legal JDK 6 (e.g. icedtea-bin or icedtea) or to create a local version of the the virtual/jdk-1.6.0 ebuild (-r2 at present) that includes sun-jdk-1.6.0.45 (or whatever newer version if you have a support subscription.)  I did the latter, as I need sun's to support some old work-related code. Otherwise icedtea is the better choice.

Note that 1.6.0_45 is considered seriously insecure these days, so only use it for building or selected applications where you're 100% sure it's necessary; do NOT set it as your system or user JDK and even more so do not let it install the nsplugin.